# How to make category-xxx.php editable in dashboard?

Tags: wordpress

I have a lot of category.xxx.php and category-yyy.php, each with a specific introductory text.

How to enablee my client to edit this text in the dashboard ?

Comment: please click the checkbox if the answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

They already can. In the dashboard go to "Appearance" --> "Editor"